# Remove existing and assign new categories to existing product while updating it programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento2.3, programmatically

How can I remove existing and assign new categories to product programmatically in magento 2 while updating product data.

```
 <?php

 $newCategoryIds = array(5,6);

 $existingProductId = 25;

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($existingProductId);

 $_product->setName('New name xyz'); // Name of Product

 $existing = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 

 print_r($existing);// Return existing assign categories like Array(3,4)

 $_product->setCategoryIds([]); // Want to remove existing categories so i can assign updated categories but its not working

 $_product->save();

 $_product->setCategoryIds($newCategoryIds); // It's also not remove existing categories.

 $_product->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both given solution but none of them work for me. Although both answer were correct. Actually i was updating categories of product before saving products data `$_product->save();` of same product.

```
<?php

 $newCategoryIds = array(5,6);

 $existingProductId = 25;

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($existingProductId);

 $_product->setName('New name xyz'); // Name of Product

 $_product->save();


/*
* Manage Product Categories after product save (While you are running script to update products)
* */

$categoryLinkManagementInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
$categoryLinkManagementInterface->assignProductToCategories($_product->getSku(), $newCategoryIds);
```

Comment: Where is delete?? and you d'ont tell us that youre product aren't saved

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet function assignProductToCategories will removed existing categories automatically and add new one. I have clearly says that while product is updating. Please check my question code and also before assigning categories i am saving products as well.

Comment: Ok but in this case you must change the title of your question. For other user id they have a same case ok

Comment: To do after the product save method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagementInterface
```

```
   /**
     * Assign product to category.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param array                          $categoryIds
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function assignProductToCategory($product, $categoryIds = [])
    {
        if (!empty($categoryIds)) {
            $this->categoryLinkManagementInterface->assignProductToCategories(
                $product->getSku(),
                $categoryIds
            );
        }
    }
```

So new array wipes out existing values.

Answer (score 1):

Assign Products to Category programmatically

```
<?php
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');

$category_ids = array('22','23');
$sku = '24';

$CategoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($sku, $category_ids);
?>
```

Remove Products from Category programmatically

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository');

$categoryId = 22;
$sku = '24';

$CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryId,$sku);
?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind; Do not use the objectmanager directly.